# How can I reduce the number of coldfusion threads running?

Tags: centos, java, coldfusion

I have CF running on a mediatemple DV4.0 & it seems to be running WAY more threads than necessary - enough to continuously trip the "running processes" alert that MT provides [and cannot be configured by me to allow more processes!]

- How can I configure ColdFusion to run with fewer threads?
- is this a good idea? [i.e. will it have any negative results on performance]
- will it free up some memory?

There are only 2 or 3 very light traffic sites on the server.

Comment: Do you have a code snippet for <cfthread> or are you talking about something else?

Comment: nope - like when you do a ps -ALF to get the system processes with all threads .... there's like 250 of them. according to MT that's what is tripping the alert.

Answer (score 2):

This is something you typically set in the ColdFusion Administrator, often installed on your server at the /CFIDE/administrator path. Once you login to the CF Admin, you'll want to find "Server Settings" > "Request Tuning" in the sidebar. That page will have values you can set to control how many JVM threads are allocated to handle CF requests.

Also, make sure you have the JVM heap memory set to an appropriate value for your intended use and hosting capabilities. That's in "Server Settings" > "Java and JVM."

As to whether or not reducing worker threads is a good idea, well, that really just depends on your load and for what- under a given load, limited server resource your threads will contend.

Comment: hmmm been through that, it won't let me set the max number of threads below 50 or the max queued threads below 1000. Even after a restart they just default back to these numbers.